# How to use more advanced features in TinyTest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, meteor, tinytest

I am using TinyTest to run my unit tests, but I am struggling to find official documentation on the more advanced methods.

There's of course the [EventedMind video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-testing-packages-with-tinytest), the [Meteor Cookbook](https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/writing.unit.tests.md). `numtel` provides some unofficial documentation in [his repo](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-leaderboard-tinytest#tinytest-documentation). But no official documentation.

Specifically, I am struggling to understand how to use `test.expect_fail()`, or `test.runId()`, `test.ok()`, `test.fail()` and `test.exception()`

Comment: I tried too to use tinytest but I switched to jasmine since its better documented and has all the features from tinytest(ex. package testing)

Comment: There's no documentation, but you can see a list of all available options in the source code https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tinytest/tinytest.js